# Python - Exclude variable if list element doesn't exist

Tags: python, list, indexing

Python novice here - was unable to find anything similar online.

I am trying to analyze a large data set containing many rows with varying column lengths. An example of my data may be: "LY R15 515 750 601 999" where the number of elements is different for each row. I want the column variables to refer to each subsequent element, but only if that element exists. I am going to use all column variables for if statements with numeric expressions later on.

```
data = 'LY R15 515 750 601 999'
remove_blanks = ['']
entries = data.split()
''.join([i for i in entries if i not in remove_blanks])
trash = (entries[0], entries[1])
time = int(entries[2])
column_1 = int(entries[3])
column_2 = int(entries[4])
column_3 = int(entries[5])
column_4 = int(entries[6])
column_5 = int(entries[7])
column_6 = int(entries[8])
column_7 = int(entries[9])
column_8 = int(entries[10])
column_9 = int(entries[11])
column_10 = int(entries[12])
column_11 = int(entries[13])
column_12 = int(entries[14])
column_13 = int(entries[15])
column_14 = int(entries[16])
column_15 = int(entries[17])
column_16 = int(entries[18])
column_17 = int(entries[19])
column_18 = int(entries[20])
print(entries)
```

The error I am receiving:

> column_3 = int(entries[5])
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

I understand it is happening because that element does not exist in the list. Essentially, if an element does not exist, I do not want that variable to be considered. Please help!

P.S. I am sure there is a much simpler way to write this, so if there is, please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dictionary could probably do the work

```
variables = {}
for ix, value in enumerate(entries[3:]):
    variables["column_{0}".format(ix)] = int(value)
```

You get

```
{'column_1': 601, 'column_0': 750, 'column_2': 999}
```

However, it would be much easier for you to use some package like pandas for data analysis

Comment: Thank you for the help. How would you call those variables? I keep getting an error saying unresolved reference 'column_0' if I try "print(column_0)" or "if column_0 >= 0:" for any of the variables, this error occurs.

Comment: The variables are then the keys of your dictionary. You do for example print(variables['column_0']) and get 750

Comment: Okay I see now. It works for all elements that exist! Though, like I said above, if my list does not include enough elements, I want the variables that do not get assigned a value to not be considered by an if statement with a numeric expression. Is there a way to do that using this dictionary? Perhaps if I put an example of my code it would make more sense?

Comment: So you loop over the keys of your dictionary - your keys are the variables that got a value assigned to. In the example above you don't do `variables['column_8']`, because this key does not exist. You do `for key in variables: print(variables[key])`

Comment: This seems to be causing more issues. I am trying to use specific column values (list elements) to convert from decimal to ascii (i.e. digit = [chr(key) for key in variables]. This returns an error "an integer is required (got type str)" in the conversion code. Any way to continue using the dictionary to mitigate this issue?

Comment: Was able to figure it out. Used a try function to invalidate some of the column variables. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Having variables named `column_1` to `column_18` is not very handy.

Instead of

```
column_1 = int(entries[3])
column_2 = int(entries[4])    
column_3 = int(entries[5])
... etc, etc ...
```

consider

```
column = [None] + [int(v) for v in entries[3:]]
```

and then use `column[3]` instead of `column_3`.

The `[None] +` is a dodge to get the list subscripts (which are zero based) to match your variable names, which are 1-based.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help. I see what you mean with the 0-based and 1-based conflict, makes sense :)

Comment: Your answer made it much simpler, but doing something like print(column[10]) still results in the same error when that element does not exist. I was hoping to find a way to have the script disregard the columns that do not exist.